# Python thread Lock

Tags: python, locking

I have written a threaded python code using Lock()(defined in a global variable). The thread should execute some code first, then after finishing, it can be called again.
The code looks like this:

```
with lock:
 pid = os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "command", "command", "args")
 os.system("some command")
 os.waitpid(pid, 0);
```

The problem is that the lock works, but the child exits (It should be running) when the thread is called again.

Comment: Except for using `lock` I can't see anything related to multithreading in your code.

Comment: It is just a minimalistic code.. I call the thread with "start_new_thread" and I am expecting that the child spawned will remain but it exits when the thread is called again

Comment: Well, another thread will not enter `with lock:` block until the first thread leaves it. And since you have `os.waitpid(pid, 0)` then the first thread leaves the block after the child terminates.

Comment: Thanks for your response so far. But, what I want to do is running the process in background and wait for it (it should continue running for a long time), then when I call the thread again, another child should be spawned and running also, so multiple childs should run at the same time but one by one not simultanesously

Comment: I don't see the point of using `lock` in this scenario. Remove it and see what happens. If the code executed in the thread doesn't modify variables visible for other threads there will be no issues.

Comment: Well, I need lock (or maybe another method), because I am running a child that will use a tcp traffic redirected by an iptables rule (I have one external port and the iptables redirects the tcp traffic to a local port each time for the spawned child). When The thread is called concurrently, Iptables rule will be overritten and everything will be not OK ! 

So, I need to execute the child and the iptables rule not simultanously but one by one. I have found Lock but it seems not resolving the problem

Comment: Your requirements are quite contradictory then. In the question you're complaining that the children don't run in parallel. Now you're telling us that they can't run in parallel because of iptables.

Comment: The problem is still the same, I was questioning about the origin of problem ! I just gave more details !

Comment: No need to shout. I'm trying to understand.

Comment: I am still looking for a decent solution..